# Python: Creating multiple plots in one figure with for loop

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I have tried to create a 2 row, 3 column grid of plots (each having multiple data plotted on it) using matplotlib.  However, no matter what I try, the final saved figure is just one of the plots, with the rest blank.  I know the other were produced, but they are not appearing in the final image.  Here is one basic version of what I'm trying.

The commented out pieces show some alternatives that I have seen.

```
f,axarr = plt.subplots(2,3, sharex='col', sharey='row')

for i,someargs in enumerate(namelist):
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = somefunction(someargs)  #output data
    ax = axarr.flat[i]  #or ax=axarr[row,col]
    ax.plot(x1,y1)
    ax.plot(x2,y2)
plt.savefig("name")
#or f.savefig("name")
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am doing this?  The image I am getting is located at https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyZCt.png
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that you store your axes in `axarr`, then fetch the current axis from `axrr`

Comment: Have you checked that `len(namelist)` is `6`? Your code works here.

Comment: namelist in my case is of length 5 because I only have 5 plots.

Comment: I added an image of what I'm getting.  If it's working for others, then I'm really not sure what's going on.

Comment: I would break down the code until you have a reproducible example. Replace your data by dummy data. While doing so, you will probably find the issue yourself. If not you can show us code we can run and it's much easier for us to find the problem.

Comment: @opaco Have you tried the answer I have posted?

Comment: Your answer works (as does what I originally posted) with simple test data.  I posted an update with an answer to what I have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some some time closely looking at what I'm running, I've found that the problem might lie somewhere with the function I am using to generate data and how it interacts with the loop.  Indeed, using basic test data causes no problem.

That function does a lot of stuff (and requires parallelism), so it's difficult to tell exactly what it's doing.

I'm not really sure what went wrong, but I fixed my problem by storing the data first, and then accessing/plotting it in the manner I posted or similarly to the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is the way you can use a loop to generate your `subplots` and you can hide the axes which you do not need:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
fig ,axs=plt.subplots(2,3, sharex='col', sharey='row')
axs[-1,-1].axis('off')
namelist=['a','b','c','d','e']
ax=axs.ravel()
for i,someargs in enumerate(namelist):
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = somefunction(someargs)
    ax[i].plot(x1,y1)
    ax[i].plot(x2,y2)
```