# Producing a plot using a for loop

Tags: python, loops, plot

I want to select from a dataframe based on a name. Then I want to plot the data on a single graph using a for loop.

```
df = pd.read_csv ('Kd.csv')
watertype = ['Evian','Volvic','Buxton']
for type in watertype:
    sdf = df[(df['Water']==type)]
    Na = sdf.iloc[:,13]
    Kd = sdf.iloc[:,2]
    plt.plot(Na,Kd,'o')
plt.show()`
```

Multiple graphs produced instead of overlaying them on a single graph.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120043/python-creating-multiple-plots-in-one-figure-with-for-loop

Comment: hey it should work, so you get 3 plots?